# Query to order rows by id and parent_id

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table that contains nested data, I need to order the rows by `id` and `parent_id`

This is the actual table:

```
select * from commission_category;

+----+-------+-----------+
| id | code  | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
| -1 | " "   | null      |
|  1 | "AU"  | null      |
|  7 | "AI"  | null      |
|  8 | "AEM" | null      |
|  9 | "SPE" | null      |
| 10 | "AEN" | null      |
| 11 | "FV"  | null      |
| 13 | "PRO" | null      |
| 17 | "AF"  | 9         |
| 12 | "IND" | 1         |
| 15 | "CIV" | 9         |
| 16 | "CON" | 1         |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

---

This is the desired order:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | code  | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
| -1 | " "   | null      |
|  1 | "AU"  | null      |
| 16 | "CON" | 1         |
| 12 | "IND" | 1         |
|  7 | "AI"  | null      |
|  8 | "AEM" | null      |
|  9 | "SPE" | null      |
| 17 | "AF"  | 9         |
| 15 | "CIV" | 9         |
| 10 | "AEN" | null      |
| 11 | "FV"  | null      |
| 13 | "PRO" | null      |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

The order that I need require to order the table by `id` after that by `parent_id`. The `parent_id` need to be near the row with the corresponding `id`.

**Example**:

The first row have the `id = 1` that is the `parent_id` of the next rows.

```
|  1 | "AU"  | null      |
| 16 | "CON" | 1         |
| 12 | "IND" | 1         |
```

---

This is what I have produced:

```
select * from (select * from commission_category order by id asc) subs order by subs.parent_id desc

+----+-------+-----------+
| id | code  | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
| -1 | " "   | null      |
|  1 | "AU"  | null      |
|  7 | "AI"  | null      |
|  8 | "AEM" | null      |
|  9 | "SPE" | null      |
| 10 | "AEN" | null      |
| 11 | "FV"  | null      |
| 13 | "PRO" | null      |
| 17 | "AF"  | 9         |
| 15 | "CIV" | 9         |
| 16 | "CON" | 1         |
| 12 | "IND" | 1         |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

What I'm missing in the query?

Comment: Can you describe the desired order as it's not clear to me what your sample results are ordered by? The reason why your version doesn't work is because the order of your subquery is completely discarded when you order it again in the outer query. You'd need to put all your ORDER BYs at a single level.

Comment: i have tried to update the question to better explain the required output order. What do you mean with put the order by at single level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need multiple levels of sorting:

```
select * 
from commission_category
order by coalesce(parent_id, id), 
         (parent_id is null)::int desc, 
         id desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a67978bb5a4e3e4d166b18db5f48a19).
Results:

```
> id | code | parent_id
> -: | :--- | --------:
> -1 |      |      null
>  1 | AU   |      null
> 16 | CON  |         1
> 12 | IND  |         1
>  7 | AI   |      null
>  8 | AEM  |      null
>  9 | SPE  |      null
> 17 | AF   |         9
> 15 | CIV  |         9
> 10 | AEN  |      null
> 11 | FV   |      null
> 13 | PRO  |      null
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what is doing in `coalesce(parent_id, id), (parent_id is null)::int desc`?

Comment: `coalesce(parent_id, id)` sorts by parent_id when it is not null (for the children so that they are near their parents) and when it is null by id (for the parents). `(parent_id is null)::int desc` sorts each group so that the parent is on top and then the children follow.

Comment: You can replace `(parent_id is null)::int desc` with `parent_id NULLS FIRST`